# .Net Core Equivalent to CryptoJS.AES.encrypt

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, encryption, asp.net-core-3.1, cryptojs

I have below JavaScript code that uses `CryptoJS.AES.encrypt` function from `CryptoJS` library and I am looking for equivalent .Net Core code, can anyone please guide?

```
        var myData = '';
        var key1 = '';
        var key2 = '';

        var encryptedData = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(myData.substr(0, myData.length - 1)), CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(key1),
            {
                keySize: 128 / 8,
                iv: CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(key2),
                mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
                padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
            });
```

**Edit**

I have found below code for .Net Core:

```
public string EncryptString(string text, string keyString, string ivString)
        {
            var key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(keyString);

            using (var aesAlg = Aes.Create())
            {
                using (var encryptor = aesAlg.CreateEncryptor(key, aesAlg.IV))
                {
                    using (var msEncrypt = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        using (var csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                        using (var swEncrypt = new StreamWriter(csEncrypt))
                        {
                            swEncrypt.Write(text);
                        }

                        var iv = aesAlg.IV;

                        var decryptedContent = msEncrypt.ToArray();

                        var result = new byte[iv.Length + decryptedContent.Length];

                        Buffer.BlockCopy(iv, 0, result, 0, iv.Length);
                        Buffer.BlockCopy(decryptedContent, 0, result, iv.Length, decryptedContent.Length);

                        return Convert.ToBase64String(result);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

But I am not sure how to specify these options as specified in JavaScript code:

```
 {
                    keySize: 128 / 8,
                    iv: CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(key2),
                    mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
                    padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
                }
```

**Edit 2**

I updated my C# code following suggestions from Topaco and below is my code.
But when I test it the output of my C# code and JavaScript code is different can anyone please guide what's missing?

```
public string RequestHash(string text, string keyString, string ivString)
        {
            var key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(keyString);
            var iv = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(ivString);

            using (var aesAlg = Aes.Create())
            {
                using (var encryptor = aesAlg.CreateEncryptor(key, iv))
                {
                    using (var msEncrypt = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        using (var csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                        using (var swEncrypt = new StreamWriter(csEncrypt))
                        {
                            swEncrypt.Write(text);
                        }

                        var decryptedContent = msEncrypt.ToArray();
                        return Convert.ToBase64String(decryptedContent);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Both codes are different: The C# code uses a _random_ IV and concatenates it with the ciphertext. The CryptoJS code, on the other hand, applies a _static_ IV and does not perform concatenation. The static IV makes the CryptoJS code insecure.

Comment: Regarding the parameters: In the C# code the key size is _implicitly_ determined by the key, CBC and PKCS7 are used _by default_.

Comment: I see, thanks for your reply. Can you please share some more details on why having static IV makes code insecure? I will have to confirm but I believe Key2 is also randomly generated. Assuming key2 or ivy is also randomly generated, can you please guide what changes would I need in C# EncryptString() method if the iv is also provided as a string parameter to this function so that it uses the ivy string passed to this function.
Thanks!

Comment: Do the same with the IV as with the key (i.e. replace `aesAlg.IV` with `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("<your IV>"))` and just `return Convert.ToBase64String(decryptedContent)`. Regarding the insecurity of reused key/IVs you can find a lot of information on SO or also [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization_vector).

Comment: Thank you so much Topaco really appreciate, can you please post the update code as answer?

Comment: Do we also need to set `KeySize` i.e. `aesAlg.KeySize = 128 / 8` as done in JavaScript code?

Comment: The key size is derived in the C# code from the passed key and does not need to be set explicitly.

Comment: Can you please take a look at `Edit 2` I updated my C# code following your suggestions. But when I test it the output of my C# code and JavaScript code is different can you please guide what's missing?

Comment: When testing the C# code, did you consider that in the CryptoJS code the last character of the plaintext is not taken into account: `CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(myData.substr(0, myData.length - 1))`?

Comment: Oh sorry I missed that, thanks for pointing out, it in fact fixed the issue. Really appreciate your help Topaco :)

Comment: You could post the updated code to answer your own question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you so much Topaco for your help, really appreciate!

Here's my final code:

```
public string RequestHash(string text, string keyString, string ivString)
{
    var key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(keyString);
    var iv = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(ivString);

    using (var aesAlg = Aes.Create())
    {
        using (var encryptor = aesAlg.CreateEncryptor(key, iv))
        {
            using (var msEncrypt = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (var csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                using (var swEncrypt = new StreamWriter(csEncrypt))
                {
                    swEncrypt.Write(text);
                }

                var decryptedContent = msEncrypt.ToArray();
                return Convert.ToBase64String(decryptedContent);
            }
        }
    }
}
```